# Bottom-up communication Python

Tags: python, oop

I have 2 classes, `A` and `B`.

`A` has an instance of `B` in its body and a `counter` of type `int`. Let's suppose that `B`, for some reasons, wants to increase the value of `counter`inside its parent `A`.

So classes should look like :

```
from bTest import B


class A:
    counter: int
    b: B

    def __init__(self, b: B):
        self.counter = 0
        self.b = b
```

And in an other file `B` :

```
from aTest import A
class B:
    a: A

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def increaseA(self):
        self.a.counter += 1

    def setA(self, na: A):
        self.a = na
        self.increaseA()
```

This is the main :

```
from aTest import A
from bTest import B

b = B()
a = A(b)
b.setA(a)
print(str(a.counter))
```

Now when I run it this is the output :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'A' from partially initialized module 'aTest' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Let's assume that I want to create a communication between `B` and `A`, so I'm not interested in a better design or change responsibilities.

I'm very stuck on this circular import, I don't understand if it's fixable or not.

Comment: Have you tried putting them into the same module? In any case, you need to pass the B instance to the A's constructor when initializing the B instance: `self.a = A(self)`.

Comment: The module ``aTest`` only imports ``bTest`` for the sake of the type hint, right? So you don't really "need" that import.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I want to keep them separed. By the way I added "self" but got the same error.

Comment: @MikeScotty I didn't get you mate sorry, what I should do?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I put them in the same file but still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

What @MikeScotty suggested you is:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from bTest import B
```

In A file.